# Center text in SuperCardToast

Tags: android

I'm using the SuperCardToast framework to display notifications.  I want the text to be centered instead of left aligned.  Is that possible?

```
    SuperCardToast superCardToast = new SuperCardToast(activity);
    superCardToast.setText(activity.getString(R.string.No_internet_connection));
    superCardToast.setBackground(R.color.orange);
    superCardToast.setIndeterminate(true);
    superCardToast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [supercardtoast.xml](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts/blob/master/supertoasts/res/layout/supercardtoast.xml)
and
[SuperCardToast.java](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts/blob/master/supertoasts/src/com/github/johnpersano/supertoasts/SuperCardToast.java)

I think it's not possible,because there is no API can set gravity of mMessageTextView in SuperCardToast.java

If have only one card once, You can try a trick:

```
SuperCardToast superCardToast = new SuperCardToast(activity);
superCardToast.setText(activity.getString(R.string.No_internet_connection));
superCardToast.setBackground(R.color.orange);
superCardToast.setIndeterminate(true);
superCardToast.show();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(findViewById(R.id.message_textview)!=null){
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_textview)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }, 50);
```

it works